# Intellij IDEA - skip jaCoCo while running individual tests

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, jacoco

I have gradle JaCoCo configuration as advised by the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html):

```
test {
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}
jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
}
```

I have Intellij IDEA configuration to run tests with Gradle. Currently when I run individual tests from IDEA, it also launches jaCoCo coverage report, which takes time and I would like to avoid.

So I would like:

1. to keep my gradle configuration so that coverage reports run every time I run build
2. Do not run JaCoCo when running tests from IDEA

I have tried changing gradle tasks definition in IDEA to include `-x jacocoTestReport`, but it has no effect. I tried to change test run configuration, but its getting reset for every new test,

Answer (score -1):

Please try to set the `Run tests using` to "Intellij IDEA" from `Preferences/Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle` .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D83WY.png)

Comment: This worked for me, but you have to make sure you delete your previous Run Configuration. If you just hit play on the existing one, it will still run in Gradle.